# Difference between DateField and DateChooser

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I want to know the Difference between DateField and DateChooser in FLEX. I know the UI changes but i want the difference other than its UI, Properties, Method etc...

Thanks in adnvance

Comment: Well, to my knowledge the main differences between the two extend to the simple fact that DateField is a TextInput field showing dates, which results in it having the properties _parseFunction_ and _formatString_. Also since the two are often paired, the DateField has the _dropdownFactory_ property which creates the DateChooser.  Also since they usually go together, the properties you specify for the DateField are as far as i know inherited to the DateChooser

Comment: Good Question... I also finding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **DateChooser** control displays the name of a month, the year, and a grid of the days of the month. It contains columns labeled for the days of the week. This control is useful in applications where you want a continually visible calendar. The user can select a single date from the grid. The control contains forward and back arrow buttons to let you change the month and year. You can disable the selection of certain dates, and limit the display to a range of dates.

The **DateField** control is a text field that displays the date with a calendar icon on its right side. When a user clicks anywhere inside the bounding box of the control, a date chooser that is identical to the **DateChooser** control pops up. If no date has been selected, the text field is blank and the current month is displayed in the date chooser.

When the date chooser is open, users can click the month scroll buttons to scroll through months and years, and select a date. When the user selects a date, the date chooser closes and the text field displays the selected date.

This control is useful in applications where you want a calendar selection tool, but want to minimize the space that the date information takes up.

From docs:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d9b.html

Cheers